# Why is Red Leader flying a Y-Wing?

Tags: star-wars, comics, a-new-hope

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127879/20774), I linked an image from [Perfect Evil, Part I](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Perfect_Evil) which seems to show Red Leader exploding **in a Y-Wing**.

[image]

As any fule kno, Red Leader was flying a X-Wing [when he crashed](https://youtu.be/2WBG2rJZGW8?t=9m35s). So why was Red Leader depicted in a Y-Wing? Is this just a canon mistake or something *[more sinister](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bW7Op86ox9g)* ?

Comment: Are you implying he was left-handed, or that left-handed people fly Y-wings?

Comment: Manga error, I guess. In the movie, Red Leader is shown in an X-wing multiple times, every time

Comment: @Petersaber - Actually, it's my error.

Comment: @T.J.L.  Very dexterous of you

Comment: @Richard oh, ok, good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two questions here.

### Is this actually Red Leader?

**The short answer is No.** What I originally thought was Red Leader in an earlier panel is in fact "[Davish Krall](http://www.starwars.com/databank/rebel-pilots-biography-gallery)", AKA "Pops".  Pops flew **a Y-Wing** under the call sign "Gold-Five" and was one of the pilots killed by Vader in his initial assault. Note the distinctive crossed roundels on his helmet.

[image]

### So where is Red Leader?

I cut off the bottom of the picture without realising what it showed. It's most likely that he was in one of the X-wings pictured being blown up in the panel below and almost certainly pictured in the bottom panel showing an impact on the Death Star's surface. It would appear that his final scream isn't depicted.

[image]